# Is an analog radio tuner more robust in a nuclear blast than a digital tuner?

Tags: radio, emf

Some radio receivers seem to have analog tuners (i.e. you turn a knob and it's completely mechanical), whereas others are more digital i.e. they can search for stations, save them as "presets", and shows the frequency on an LCD display, etc.

While the digital variety seems nicer, I'm wondering if it is less reliable in the case of high EMF radiation (as might be caused by a nuclear blast) compared to the analog type.

Comment: Both will probably be fried, but the one with less semiconductors will probably have better chances. An all-vacuum tubes one would be ideal.

Comment: Why are you worrying about the just tuner and not the entire radio? Either way, the one with the biggest single semiconductor and no MOSFETs is better off.

Comment: Question as worded is rather broad.  Are your asking about EMP (Electromagnetic Pulses) generated by a high altitude nuclear explosion, or about low altitude (couple of hundred feet altitude) exploasions, or something else.  The electromagnetic effects are different.

Comment: both will be vaporized

Comment: Some of us are old enough to remember car radios with fully analog tuners that had typically five or six presets. The preset was entirely mechanical. Pushing any of the five or six buttons on the radio's face would rotate the tuner shaft to a specific position. You could also tune the radio with a knob, and pulling any of the buttons _out_ and then pressing it back in again would cause it to remember the current shaft position. I regret that I never disassembled one to learn more about how it worked.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Is that why you had to push the buttons with so much force? It was like pushing buttons on a walkman that drove a mechanical assembly. I was like 6 years old and remember thinking "*what is with these buttons?*"

Comment: @DKNguyen, Yes. Exactly. When you pushed the button, you were pushing on some kind of connecting rod and crank gizmo. In the worst case, the station you wanted would be all the way at one end of the dial, and the current station was all the way at the other end. That would be a nearly 180 degree rotation of the tuner shaft, and you'd be starting from pretty close to top dead center. Plus, besides turning the shaft, you're also driving the strings and pulleys that moved the pointer from side-to-side across the dial.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Now that you mention it, I remember that you couldn't always push a random button in the middle. You had to work from whatever button towards the end and then work your way towards the other end and some buttons would be half in or half out.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that's where the term `radio button` came from

Comment: In case of high EMF worry about the often very cheap radio receiver itself blowing up long before anything else. The average FM radio out there is of very low quality, where they cheap out on everything from filters to transient protection. Also meaning that in the real world they are far more likely to blow up from lightning strikes than during some prepper nuclear apocalypse scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes I'm aware that some analog radios also had presets so I tried to elaborate it with other features (auto scan, LCD showing freq etc.). By the way, my granny had a television with 10 presets which were implemented by having 10 small tuner knobs hidden behind a panel, each corresponding to one of the preset buttons. So all the preset buttons did was to switch which of the knobs were in control.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, integrated circuits are more susceptible to EMP and radiation than discrete parts.  In that respect a simple analog radio made from a few discrete parts is more likely to survive than one that contains integrated circuits.

But unless the radio was specifically designed to survive nuclear EMP then it's likely it will burn out whether it be analog or digital.

Keeping the unit unpowered (no batteries, and unplugged, or hard power switch open) will drastically increase survivability, especially in CMOS integrated circuits.

Keeping the unit inside some sort of shielding (like a metal box) will help it survive.

If the antenna is detachable, keeping the antenna detached will help.